# use statement True and False in Python 2.7

Tags: python, if-statement, command-prompt

i wish to use a statement "`True`" and "`False`" for my Python (2.7) command prompt

```
segmentation_accuracy(reference=REFERENCE, segmented=SEGMENTED, output=OUTPUT, method=METHOD, threshold=THRESHOLD, sep=SEP, header=HEADER)
```

if header is `True` print a text file with an header, if header is `False` print a text file without an header.

in Command Prompt:

```
REFERENCE = raw_input("Reference (*.shp):")
SEGMENTED = raw_input("Segmented (*.shp):")
METHOD = raw_input("Method (ke, pu, clinton):")
if METHOD != "ke" and METHOD != "pu" and METHOD != "clinton":
    raise ValueError("%s is not a valid method" % METHOD)
if METHOD == "ke" or METHOD == "clinton":
    THRESHOLD = input("Threshold (0.0 - 1.0):")
    if not check_threshold(THRESHOLD):
        raise AccuracyException("Threshold of %s is not valid" % THRESHOLD)
else:
    THRESHOLD = None
SEP = raw_input("Sep:")
HEADER = raw_input("Header (True/False):")
if HEADER is not True or HEADER is not False:
    raise ValueError("%s is not valid" % HEADER)
# output 
OUTPUT = raw_input("Output (*.txt):")
```

when i run the command prompt in windows if i set `raw_input("Header (True/False):")` `True` or `False`, I always get the `ValueError`

i also used the combination

```
if HEADER != True or HEADER != False:
        raise ValueError("%s is not valid" % HEADER)
```

with the same problem

Comment: Do not use `is` and `is not` to compare with anything except `None`. Use `==` or `!=`. (Well, don't use anything for booleans; just `if HEADER`

Comment: Wooble, i did but i got always the same problem

Comment: (This doesn't address the `raw_input` problem, which is why I didn't post it as an answer; it's just a general point about something else wrong in your code)

Comment: @Wooble `is` is perfectly fine (encouraged even, check PEP 8) for singletons. `True` and `False` are singletons. The only reason we don't use `cond is True` and `cond is False` is because `if cond:` works just as well and is shorter, sweeter, etc.

Comment: @delnan: well, it also almost never works correctly because you can have a truthy value that is not `True` and a falsy value that is not `False`. (Guido has even explicitly said to never do this with `True` and `False` as well even if you're checking if it's both an actual boolean just because nearly every time this is written it's a bug and the 1% of the time you do mean it you should explicitly use `isinstance` to show that you know what you're doing.)

Comment: @Wooble Yes, it doesn't work if you actually want a falsy value. Neither does `==`, which is what you advertised as superior ;-) And yes, explicitly checking for bools is still a bad idea - I don't think anyone ever disagreed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value from `raw_input` is a string and not a boolean. Hence your `is not True` and `is not False` tests, although they have well-defined meaning, that meaning is not the meaning that you intend. You need to compare `HEADER` against string values.

So you would need, for example, code like this:

```
if HEADER.lower() == 'true':
```

I used `tolower()` to effect case-insensitive comparison. You may also want to strip off white space:

```
if HEADER.strip().lower() == 'true':
```

I'm sure you can fill in the test against `false` yourself.

---

Even if you did have a boolean, you should not use code like `is not True` or `is False`. You should test for truth with:

```
if somebool:
```

or

```
if not somebool:
```

because it is much more readable.

Comment: thanks for help. I tried your solution in order to update my code statement, but i got a error message. Could you write (if you have time, i dont want abuse of your time) an update of my code in order to understand better your solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: `.tolower()`?  What non-Pythonic language have you been programming in lately? ;^)

Comment: this is my error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tolower'

Comment: @DSM Thanks a lot for fixing my code. I've no idea where `tolower` came from. Too many programming languages in my life!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`HEADER` is a string, not a boolean. This will cause the `is` check to fail. Your comparison runs like this:

```
>>> "True" is not True
True
>>> "True" is not False
True
```

Note that a comparison with `==` will also fail:

```
>>> "True" == True
False
>>> "True" == False
False
```

Try comparing the value as a string:

```
if HEADER.tolower() == 'true':
    #do something
elif HEADER.tolower() == 'false:
    #do something else
```